# Is there an API for language support for google speech-to-text?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

There's a list of languages but I can't find an API call for getting it dynamically.
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages

Answer (score 3):

There is no API for doing that. Either way, you can list the available languages using code by reading the source code of the link you sent and then parsing it to list them.

If you want to use Python, you can read the source code with:

```
import requests    
SourceCode=requests.get('https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages').text
```

For parsing I would use Python library *pandas* [[1]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html), the languages are inside `<table></table>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it in Javascript, with a server.

I wanted to extract the English-language codes only so my some of my later steps may be different than what you desire, but below is my JS, followed by php since you can't parse from another website in JS from the client side

Javascript code (returns a promise):

```js
const languageCodes = await (async () => {
  let phpFetched = await fetch('grab_languages.php');
  phpFetched = await phpFetched.text();
  let htmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(phpFetched, "text/html");
 
  htmlDoc =  Array.from(htmlDoc
                        .querySelector('#lang-table-container')
                        .querySelectorAll('table tr'))
                  .slice(1)
                  .map(el => Array.from(el.querySelectorAll('td')))
                  .filter(children => children[2].innerHTML === 'Default' &&
                                      children[1].innerHTML.split('-')[0] === 'en')
                  .map(children => {
                    return {
                      code: children[1].innerHTML,
                      description: (/\(([^)]+)\)/).exec(children[0].innerHTML)[1],
                    };
                  })
                  .reduce((acc, curr) =>
                    ({ ...acc, [curr.code]: curr.description }), {});

  return htmlDoc
})();
```

Php code (I've called the file `grab_languages.php`

```php
<?php
    $url = "https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages";
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
    exit;
?>
```

I should note my code was inspired off these:

- [Is there an API for language support for google speech-to-text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50425345/is-there-an-api-for-language-support-for-google-speech-to-text)
- https://github.com/fspoettel/moneypenny/blob/acdd1fd95347bcf284a5a24e4a58186ad4545a22/src/constants.js
- and https://github.com/zevaverbach/tatt/blob/07c4728bbfb167803fd14a6416cba0d9eda0b431/tatt/vendors/google.py

and you might also find [this](https://github.com/ankit-kumar-cs/Interactive-Voice-Assistant/blob/ea4dbafc9fe52b9ab310636ecb90263d6dff14e5/Multilanguage.py) helpful if you're interested in another Python implementation